# Drag'n'Drop and Paste detection with contentEditable or designMode enabled

Tags: javascript, events, cross-browser

Does anyone of you know a **cross browser** working way to detect *paste* or *drag'n'drop* inserts into an editable html document (with designMode or contentEditable enabled).

Detecting paste works as long as the user uses the Ctrl-V shortcut as it generated key events, but if you use the browsers Edit->Paste no events are generated it seems.

Comment: I suggest you look at CodeMirror (http://marijn.haverbeke.nl/codemirror/) and see what the author did.

Comment: It seems to detect paste well, but with drag and drop you can sneak code in undetected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `paste` event that works for all pastes (including via context or edit menus) in an editable document, in Firefox starting version 3.0, WebKit for a few years (not sure of version number) and IE since 5.5. Adding the `paste` event handler to the body element works in all these browsers.

I'm afraid I don't have any insight on drag and drop events: on the editors I've worked on I've had good reason to explicitly disable drag and drop.

Answer (score 0):

To handle drag'n'drop you can subscribe on mouseUp event. But in this case you have to parse  already pasted html.